# Makefile: compare two version string values from git tag and package.json

Tags: git, shell, makefile, jq, package.json

I'm trying to compare version values between the pacakge.json latest git tag so that I can fail the CI build if the versions do not match. I've created a make target that will take the two version values and do a string comparison to make sure they are the same, although I'm open to numeric comparsions if possible.

```
PKG_VERSION=$(shell echo v$$(jq .version package.json))
LATEST_TAG=$(shell git describe --tags --abbrev=0 $$(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
enforce-versions:
    @echo "Comparing \"$(PKG_VERSION)\" & \"$(LATEST_TAG)\""
ifeq ($(PKG_VERSION), $(LATEST_TAG))
    exit 0;
else
    exit 1;
endif
```

Output:

```
$ make enforce-versions 
Comparing "v1.0.0" & "v1.1.0"
exit 1;
make: *** [enforce-versions] Error 1
$ make enforce-versions
Comparing "v1.1.0" & "v1.1.0"
exit 1;
make: *** [enforce-versions] Error 1
```

Comment: Do you get different results if you `strip()`  the parameters? (I don't see how that'd change anything, but thought it'd be worth a try).

Comment: Try removing the space in your ifeq -- I believe certain versions of make will not strip leading/trailing whitespace of arguments before comparing strings.

Comment: Interesting -- if I force one, but not both, of the variables to end with `\r`, the `echo` makes them appear the same, but they compare differently. Perhaps it's a line-ending issue?

Comment: Just a side note -- it's likely cleaner to do the comparison inside of a recipe line rather than use an `ifeq`-- something like `@[ "$(PKG_VERSION)" -eq "$(LATEST_TAG)" ] && exit 0 || exit 1`

Comment: At first I thought removing the space in the ifeq statement was going to fix that but it doesn't. Interestingly using plain strings in the variables makes the comparison work, so I'm not sure if the issue is with the command substitutions or something.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry your solution of the shell line fixed my problem, feel free to add as an answer.

Comment: The question remains why you encountered a problem in the first place (I'm actually quite curious...).   I'll post my solution for future readers, but give Philippe's answer a try to see if that fixes it.   If it does, that should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @hardcorehenry I did try that but it also did not help, see my comment below their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the comparison in the shell command instead of inside of an `ifeq` as so:

```
PKG_VERSION=$(shell echo v$$(jq .version package.json))
LATEST_TAG=$(shell git describe --tags --abbrev=0 $$(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
enforce-versions:
    @echo "Comparing \"$(PKG_VERSION)\" & \"$(LATEST_TAG)\""
    @[ "$(PKG_VERSION)" = "$(LATEST_TAG)" ]
```

Notice you don't need the explicit `exit 0` or `exit 1` in this case.   If the tags are not equal, the command will return false, which will cause make to fail the recipe line, and return 1

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to remove \r:

```
PKG_VERSION=$(shell echo v$$(jq .version package.json | tr -d $$\'\\r\'))
```

You may need to apply the pipe to LATEST_TAG as well.

Comment: I did try this but it did not help, I even piped the variables through xxd as an earlier step and it reported that the strings were exactly the same.

Comment: @danielcooperxyz Can you paste the version to show how you compared with xxd ?